# Как заставить работать Vue директивы во вставленном куске HTML кода?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть `.vue` файл, в котором есть шаблон. В этот шаблон в функции происходит вставка HTML куска с Vue директивами и компонентами.

```
let element = document.getElementById('js-container')
element.innerHTML = '<div><!-- HTML код с компонентами и директивами Vue --></div>'
Vue.compile(element.innerHTML)
```

В результате я получаю страницу, на которой расположен этот код, без какой либо компиляции Vue. То есть в исходном коде страницы (в браузере) все Vue директивы отображаются как атрибуты HTML тегов. И компоненты точно также - как HTML теги с атрибутами.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вставить кусок HTML кода, который содержит Vue компоненты и директивы, а затем заставить его работать?

Answer (score 3):

Вы чет походу не поняли Vue.js вот

> в том то и дело просто html код вставить можно (будет просто html код). что бы работало как vue нужно делать так как в документации. что бы была вся польза от реактивности фреймворка. Вся работа происходит под капотом. И он должен знать заранее все окружение.

```js
// регистрация
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>Пользовательский компонент!</div>'
})
// создание корневого экземпляра
new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})

// или же более подробно

var Child = {
  template: '<div> {{ message }} я Пользовательский компонент 2!</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      message: 'привет!'
    }
  }
}
new Vue({
  // ...
  el: '#example2',
  components: {
    // <my-component> будет доступен только в шаблоне родителя
    'my-component': Child
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<div id="example2">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

[вот тут подробнее](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: Самое первое мое предложение прочтите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я думаю он имел ввиду так, как с помощью нативного свойства elem.innerHTML = '<li v-for="item in items"></li>' заставить работать vue директиву.

Comment: я и говорю что вы не правильно поняли `vue.js`. в том то и дело просто html код вставить можно (будет просто html код). что бы работало как `vue` нужно делать так как в документации. что бы была вся польза от реактивности фреймворка.